# How to use Laravel + elixir + webpack + vue + hot module reload?

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js, webpack-hmr

I've tried everything I've found to setup laravel 5.3 with elixir + webpack + vue + hot module reload and I can't achieve it.

When I do gulp watch I can't run the webpack dev server with hot module reload. I've searched for a solution for a few days and I haven't found anything.

Do you know how to set it up?

Answer (score 1):

I've just been trying to figure this out myself and discovered the new replacement for Elixir: Mix. I've just installed it on an existing Laravel 5.3 app and I now have HMR with webpack. See the instructions to install it here: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/how-to-elixir-vue-browsersync-vueify-hotreload

Since elixir does a lot of magic behind the scene, it can be tricky to add something like vueify hot reload.

Comment: This is for browserify. Not for webpack.